# how to access "this" from a prototype function that calls another prototype function

Tags: javascript

I am adding a wrapper around a function that I've declared in a prototype. the base function in the prototype works. When I try to call the wrapper function it tells me that "this.elem" has an undefined value. why doesn't "this" work in the wrapper function?

```html
<script>
  function Messages(eleLocator) {
    this.elem = eleLocator();
  }

  Messages.prototype['works'] = function(...args) {
    let output = '';

    const span = document.createElement("span");

    output += args.reduce((rv, arg) => {
      return rv + ' ' + (typeof arg === "object" && (JSON || {}).stringify ? JSON.stringify(arg) : arg);
    });

    const txt = document.createTextNode(output);
    span.append(txt);
    span.append(document.createElement('br'));

    this.elem.append(span);
  }

  Messages.prototype['nope'] = function(...args) {
    Messages.prototype.works('noper', ...args);
  }
</script>

<div id="Messages"></div>

<script>
  const dbg = new Messages(() => document.getElementById("Messages"));

  dbg.works('this', 'works');
  dbg.nope('not', 'this');
</script>
```

Comment: At a guess, `Messages.prototype.works(...)` should be `this.works(...)`. Or possibly, `Messages.prototype.works.apply(this, ...)`. The reason being that calling it the way you are doesn't set up `this` the way you'd need it set up. `this` ends up being `Messages.prototype` rather than the object created via `new Messages(...)` from earlier so of course there's no `elem` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `nope` function, instead of calling `works` from the prototype function, call it from the instance.

```js
function Messages(eleLocator) {
  this.elem = eleLocator();
}
Messages.prototype.works = function(...args) {
  let output = '';
  const span = document.createElement("span");
  output += args.reduce((rv, arg) => {
    return rv + ' ' + (typeof arg === "object" && (JSON || {}).stringify ? JSON.stringify(arg) : arg);
  });
  const txt = document.createTextNode(output);
  span.append(txt);
  span.append(document.createElement('br'));
  this.elem.append(span);
}

Messages.prototype.nope = function(...args) {
  this.works('noper', ...args); // <------ LOOK HERE =====<<<
}

const dbg = new Messages(() => document.getElementById("Messages"));
dbg.works('this', 'works');
dbg.nope('not', 'this');
```

```html
<div id="Messages"></div>
```

Comment: You should include an explanation of what you’ve changed and how that fixes the issue

Comment: thanks. didn't think about using "this" instead.